# iOS universal app acting weird

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

I just converted my iPhone app yesterday to a universal app. I made the appropriate changes, but everytime I add new png files or icons, it gives me this error:

```
No such file or directory (/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP-exqfnpxyqlazbechywnebtxqcykj/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/APP.app/APP)
```

I am not sure what is causing this. I keep following the steps described in [this blog](http://dhilipsiva.blogspot.se/2012/07/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file.html). But it doesn't work. I've even tried resarting my computer several times. Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Post the Xcode build log.  Incidentally that blog talks about a different problem to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the derived data from the Orginizer window just as the link said. What you also could do is click "Clean build folder" under the "Product" menu by holding down the alt-key. And then clean the project as usual.

Comment: Tried it now. Didn't work. Does this happen if by chance I am not following the icon-naming convention? (It doesn't show me any warnings regarding this by the way, and I think I'm following the proper names.)

Comment: Can you see the images in your Target - Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resources? Also, can you try building the app to the simulator and your iPhone? Another thing, are the icons in your plist under "Icon files"?

Comment: I can see the files in the location you mentioned. I tried running the app on the simulator, for both iPhone and iPad, and it works fine. But it doesn't run on the devices.

Comment: Ok, have you tried deleting the app from your device and then build to it again?

Comment: Yes. More times than I can count. :/

Comment: Ouch :)... So you have tried deleting the derived folder for your app in finder as well?

Comment: Well. I did not. But somehow it has started working now. Crazy. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked! It's always a pain when stuff like that happens.